# Google Tango: Failer to connect to tango service

Tags: service, crash, tango

so i was developing with unity and google tango. After pushing my application to the tablet it crashed with the message: "Failer to connect to tango service".

After rebooting the tablet i tried to start an application which was already on the tablet and it worked in the past. But also this application crashed. After rebooting again another application also crashed.

It seems as no application is able to start. I dont know why. I googled but i could not find any information about this. There were 2 pages on stack overflow but they got removed, so i get an "page not found" page.

Anyone was an idea how to fix this or what the problem could be ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

for someone who maybe was the same prolem in the future:

solution for me was just installing the system update. It seems that the tango service is not working when the device has downloaded the updates but not installed it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when running the Depth Perception Tutorial. It can be one of two problems 1. the camera has crashed and you need to reset the device or 2. You need to download and install the latest Project Tango system update. You can do this by dragging your finger down the screen from the top left on the Project Tango device and applying the Tango Update. It will take a few minutes. You should not even have to reboot. Just Build and Run again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The are multiple causes:

1. As mentioned before - the Tango Framework on the device is out of date + Tango core app is out of date.
2. Wrong implementation of Tango object's lifecycle. Tango object has its own strict life-cycle and if you do not implement it right it causes the Tango to malfunction.
3. Try to use Tango apps in order to calibrate the device